# How append works for a string if we write it more than once

Tags: python, append

```
l=['prashanth',1,2,3]
l2=['hari','a','ram']
l.append(l.append(l2))
print(l)
```

I got the following output could anyone explain me how did we get this
['prashanth', 1, 2, 3, ['hari', 'a', 'ram'], ['hari', 'a', 'ram'], None]

Comment: Because you do `l.append(l2)` then pass that to `l.append(...)` but the result of `l.append(l2)` is `None`. Therefore, you've appended exactly two objects to `l`, `'hari','a','ram']` and `None`

Comment: that's a list, not a string. Also, `append` returns none. Finally, anything can be an element in a list.

Comment: What was unclear about the output?

Comment: You should have tried to debug for yourself. That's the only way you learn.

Answer (score 0):

l.append(l2) does not return a list, it returns a NoneType object.

```
>>> a =l.append(l2)
>>> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['prashanth',1,2,3]

l2=['hari','a','ram']
```

Now when you do `l.append(l2)`, it creates a output list `['prashanth',1,2,3, ['hari','a','ram']]` and assigns to `l`. However, it returns None type object. So, when you do `l.append(l.append(l2))` it appends None as well to previous output list and assigns it back to `l`.

So final output of `l.append(l.append(l2))` will be `['prashanth', 1, 2, 3, ['hari', 'a', 'ram'], None]`

To explain --

> Append function: Adds its argument as a single element to the end of a
>   list. The length of the list increases by one.

```
syntax: 
# Adds an object (a number, a string or a 
# another list) at the end of my_list
my_list.append(object)
```

NOTE: A list is an object. If you append another list onto a list, the first list will be a single object at the end of the list.

> extend(): Iterates over its argument and adding each element to the
>   list and extending the list. The length of the list increases by
>   number of elements in it’s argument.

```
syntax: 
# Each element of an iterable gets appended 
# to my_list
my_list.extend(iterable)
```

NOTE: A string is an iterable, so if you extend a list with a string, you’ll append each character as you iterate over the string.

> Time Complexity:
>
> Append has constant time complexity i.e.,O(1).
>
> Extend has time complexity of O(k). Where k is the length of list which need to be
>   added.